# scope laravel Empty results

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, scope

good I am trying to do searches with scoope from laravel but the result greeted me null when I make a dd in the model

model

```
    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        dd("scope: ." . $name);
        return $query->where('name', $name);
    }
    
}
```

Controller

```
 $properties = Propertie::name($request->get('name'))->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
```

I am following a guide but as it continues to appear the empty dd

Comment: The code looks good and since name is null are you sure `$request->get('name')` is valid? If you know that there is a `name` value try using this `$request->name` or `$request->input('name')`

Comment: " but the result greeted me null" what do you mean with this?

Comment: in which case you want to make a condition to show the newest, how would it be?

Comment: Sounds like your problem is fixed and asking a new question am i right?

Comment: if you can erase it

Comment: Like complete this issue or? Did my comment work tho? If so I could make an answer and all you have to do is mark my answer as correct